# How to set the range in which a density is shown in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the following plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# read some dataframe and

sns.histplot(data=df['error'],bins=20, binrange=(0,2),kde=True)
```

[image]

so you can see I have limited the range for the histogram but not for the curve. Also the curve looks suspiciously low (and wrong)

then

```
sns.histplot(data=df['c0_right_error'],bins=40, binrange=(-2,2),kde=True)
```

gives me

[image]

I also tried the density plot (which I don't know if it is correct or not)

```
sns.histplot(data=df['c0_right_error'],bins=40, binrange=(-2,2),kde=True, stat='density')
```

[image]

How can I limit the range in these plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ax.set_xlim` using the matplotlib library. Using a dummy dataset see code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.normal(size=1000)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data=df['a'],bins=40, binrange=(-2,2),kde=True, stat='density', ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image]